# Batch xcopy exclude example in bash

Tags: bash, batch-file

This is one of the rows from my in windows batch file

```
xcopy multilang\app\*.* multilang\admin /exclude:xcopy.exclude.txt /y
```

I'm trying to translate it to linux bash, so far I've got this far:

```
rsync -av multilang/app/ multilang/admin/ --exclude=
```

I'm stuck with `--exclude` value, because it must be a list of files read from file `xcopy.exclude.txt`. I know it should be possible to do with piping, just not sure how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the man pages, it looks like `rsync` has an `--exclude-from=FILE` flag you could use.

```
--exclude-from=FILE     read exclude patterns from FILE
```